# How to get a character to turn in the direction of the camera? [Unity3D]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, camera, controls

I've hit a roadblock where when I move the camera, while moving, the character rotates on the spot however, their direction in where they are heading changes when I update the left thumbstick.

This is odd as updating it in Update doesn't work and forces the character to move in circles and placing it in a bit of script that updates with the right thumbstick is moved, causes the character to rotate and move in very different directions that what I want it to go in. This is temporarily fixed when I move the left thumbstick, updating the character's movement.

The controls for this are: Left Thumbstick - Move player, Right Thumbstick - Move camera, East Button - Jump, North Button - Run.

The goal is to allow the character to rotate themselves as well as their direction when I move the camera rather than them only updating their direction when I move the left thumbstick.

Before the code, these are the packages I'm currently using within Unity that effect this: Cinemachine & Input System.

Here's the movement code that this is effecting:

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DefaultControls controls;

    [Header("Unity General")]
    [SerializeField]
    private CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cameraTransform;
    public InputActionReference cameraControl;

    [Header("General Settings")]//Player movement.
    public bool canMovePlayer;
    private Vector2 currentMovementInput;
    private Vector3 currentMovement;
    private Vector3 currentRunMovement;
    private bool isMovementPressed;
    private bool isRunPressed;
    [Space]//Animator stuff.
    public Animator characterAnimator;
    private int isWalkingHash;
    private int isRunningHash;
    [Space]//Player running speed & how fast the player will turn when going left or right.
    public float rotationFactorPerFrame = 15.0f;
    public float runMultiplier = 3.0f;
    [Space]//Default gravity for when the player is falling and gravity for when the player is grounded.
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float groundedGravity = -0.05f;
    [Space]//Playing jumping.
    public float initialJumpVelocity;
    private bool isJumpPressed = false;
    private float maxJumpHeight = 1f;
    private float maxJumpTime = 0.5f;
    private bool isJumping = false;
    private int isJumpingHash;
    private bool isJumpAnimating = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

        npcInteraction = GetComponent<NPCInteraction>();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new DefaultControls();
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        isWalkingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isWalking");
        isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
        isJumpingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isJumping");

        controls.Movement.Walking.started += OnMovementInput;
        controls.Movement.Walking.canceled += OnMovementInput;
        controls.Movement.Walking.performed += OnMovementInput;
        controls.Movement.Run.started += OnRun;
        controls.Movement.Run.canceled += OnRun;
        controls.Movement.Jump.started += OnJump;
        controls.Movement.Jump.canceled += OnJump;

        SetupJumpVariables();
    }

    private void SetupJumpVariables()
    {
        float timeToApex = maxJumpTime / 2;
        gravity = (-2 * maxJumpHeight) / Mathf.Pow(timeToApex, 2);
        initialJumpVelocity = (2 * maxJumpHeight) / timeToApex;
    }

    private void HandleJump()
    {
        if (!isJumping && controller.isGrounded && isJumpPressed)
        {
            characterAnimator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, true);
            isJumpAnimating = true;
            isJumping = true;
            currentMovement.y = initialJumpVelocity * 0.5f;
            currentRunMovement.y = (initialJumpVelocity + 0.5f) * 0.5f;
        }
        else if (!isJumpPressed && isJumping && controller.isGrounded)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isJumpPressed = context.ReadValueAsButton();
    }

    private void OnRun(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isRunPressed = context.ReadValueAsButton();
    }

    private void HandleRotation()
    {
        Vector3 positionToLookAt;

        //Change in position our character should point to.
        positionToLookAt.x = currentMovement.x;
        positionToLookAt.y = 0.0f;
        positionToLookAt.z = currentMovement.z;

        //Current rotation of our character.
        Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;

        if (currentMovementInput != Vector2.zero)
        {
            //Creates a new rotation based on where the player is currently pressing.
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(currentMovementInput.x, currentMovementInput.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y;
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, rotationFactorPerFrame * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnMovementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        currentMovementInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        currentMovement = new Vector3(currentMovementInput.x, 0f, currentMovementInput.y);
        currentRunMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x * runMultiplier;
        currentRunMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y * runMultiplier;
        MovementDirection();
        isMovementPressed = currentMovementInput.x != 0 || currentMovementInput.y != 0;
    }

    private void MovementDirection()
    {
        currentMovement = cameraTransform.forward * currentMovement.z + cameraTransform.right * currentMovement.x;
        currentMovement.y = 0f;

        currentRunMovement = cameraTransform.forward * currentRunMovement.z + cameraTransform.right * currentRunMovement.x;
        currentRunMovement.y = 0f;
    }

    private void HandleAnimation()
    {
        bool isWalking = characterAnimator.GetBool(isWalkingHash);
        bool isRunning = characterAnimator.GetBool(isRunningHash);

        if (isMovementPressed && !isWalking)
        {
            characterAnimator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, true);
        }
        else if (!isMovementPressed && isWalking)
        {
            characterAnimator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, false);
        }

        if ((isMovementPressed && isRunPressed) && !isRunning)
        {
            characterAnimator.SetBool(isRunningHash, true);
        }
        else if ((!isMovementPressed || !isRunPressed) && isRunning)
        {
            characterAnimator.SetBool(isRunningHash, false);
        }
    }

    private void HandleGravity()
    {
        bool isFalling = currentMovement.y <= 0.0f;
        float fallMultiplier = 1.5f;

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            characterAnimator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, false);
            isJumpAnimating = false;
            currentMovement.y = groundedGravity;
            currentRunMovement.y = groundedGravity;
        }
        else if (isFalling)
        {
            float previousYVelocity = currentMovement.y;
            float newYVelocity = currentMovement.y + (gravity * fallMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
            float nextYVelocity = (previousYVelocity + newYVelocity) * 0.5f;
            currentMovement.y = nextYVelocity;
            currentRunMovement.y = nextYVelocity;
        }
        else
        {
            float previousYVelocity = currentMovement.y;
            float newYVelocity = currentMovement.y + (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
            float nextYVelocity = (previousYVelocity + newYVelocity) * 0.5f;
            currentMovement.y = nextYVelocity;
            currentRunMovement.y = nextYVelocity;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        HandleRotation();
        HandleAnimation();

        controller.Move(currentMovement * Time.deltaTime);

        characterAnimator.SetFloat("Speed", controls.Movement.Walking.ReadValue<Vector2>().magnitude);

        if (isRunPressed)
        {
            controller.Move(currentRunMovement * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Move(currentMovement * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        HandleGravity();
        HandleJump();

        if (cameraControl.action.triggered)
        {
            MovementDirection();
        }

        LockOnTarget();
        Interaction();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Movement.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Movement.Disable();
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into your code that has quite deep stuff regarding the camara movement, find this simple way in which a gameObject can face the direction of the camera in a simple way. Just in case it helps. This answers directly your question "How to get a character to turn in the direction of the camera?"

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LookToCamForward : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void Start()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.forward, Camera.main.transform.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work at all, to help things out, I'm wanting the character to turn with the camera when the character is moving around. This only updates when I move the left thumbstick (this moves the character) but I want it to also update when I move the camera, and because I'm using the input system package this changes things a little as I can't use the old input system.